# Set QoS for command-line tools

Tags: command-line, apple-silicon, multitasking

I’ve finally got hold of a new Mac Studio with an M1 Ultra SoC, which I will stress mostly with scientific software run from the command line.

Some of it is compiled C/C++ (often using multitasking via [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/)), some in higher-level languages like python. What sets the [QoS](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/01/07/how-macos-controls-performance-qos-on-intel-and-m1-processors/) level for code run from within (say) terminal? I have some very long-running jobs I want to ensure live entirely on the P processors with the highest possible priority. Setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=16` (the M1 Ultra has 16 P cores) seems to do a pretty good job at this, but I would like to understand how this works in more detail).

(Ideally, this would not require any MacOS-specific calls or libraries, so it can easily compile and run on other architectures.)

Comment: Look at Unix “nice” command. This enable to set program priority.

Comment: @PtitXav Is there any documentation about the relation of `nice` to QoS? It's not clear that `nice` does anything on MacOS.

Comment: Nice enable to set (renice to modify) priority of process running in a Mac . It can increase or decrease it if a process is already started. I do not not know how it may be connected to QoS which can work on thread basis. I would assume that changing program priority may increase or decrease each different thread priority in a multi thread program.